# How to Replace char in text with another one in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, char, iteration

i'd appreciate if someone could help!
I need to replace each character in my text(encrypted,which i read from file) with another character, which i have in my Dictionary.

```
 StreamReader st = new StreamReader(@"C:\path of text");
 string text = st.ReadToEnd();
 st.Close();
 char[] textChar = text.ToCharArray();  //splitting text into characters
```

So, in my Dictionary `Dictionary<char, char> keys = new Dictionary<char,char>();` for key i have some letter, say 'n' and for value - another letter, say 'a'. So i need to replace each 'n' with 'a' in my text. Dictionary has 26 letters for keys and 26 letters for values respectively.

Now i try to replace letters and write 'decrypted' text into some file

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"path for decrypted file");

 foreach(KeyValuePair<char, char> c in keys)
 {
    for(int i =0; i< textChar.Length; i++)
    {
         if (textChar.Contains(c.Key))
         {  //if text has char as a Key in Dictionary
             textChar[i] = keys[c.Key]; //replace with its value
         }
         else 
         {
             sw.Write(textChar[i]);  //if not, just write (in case of punctuatuons in text which i dont want to replace)
         }
     }
  }
  st.Close();
  file.Close();
```

This code does not work correctly, because the replacement is wrong.
I'd be so grateful for any help!

Comment: Gyuzal do you know off hand what Keys you want to change if so then you need to have a Switch Statement inside of that for loop perhaps you have to know off hand what the keys are that you want to replace..

Comment: Gyuzal it would also help if you show a true example of the text , as well as what your expected outcome is .. not sure what you are trying to do sounds a bit suspect to me.. lol

Comment: Why do you need to replace characters in the text? Could you explain more detail? May be there is a simple solution of your problem.

Comment: yeah, i'm sorry:) i need to decrypt my text using frequency analysis, so in my Dictionary i have key-values, which i calculated. Say, 'm' must be replaced with 'c', 'n' with 'r', 'k' with 'y'etc. Example: enctypted text: mnkore -> decrypted text: crypto

Comment: can you add that example to your original question .. also will the encrypted text ever change..? if so then you need to utilize a regular Encryption / Decryption mechanism have you looked at the `Cryptography Class` look at this project what you are doing is a silly way of doing Encryption here's a good link [Cryptography in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6690/Cryptography-in-C)

Comment: this is actually not a huge project, just a small program which i wanted to use sometimes. The link you posted shows another method of encryption, using a key as a word. I use frequency analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code similar to this, I written it without Visual Studio so maybe it needs some corrections :)

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"path for decrypted file");

foreach(var key in keys)
{
  text = text.Replace(key.Key, key.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
StreamReader st = new StreamReader(@"C:\path of text");
string text = st.ReadToEnd();
st.Close();

foreach(KeyValuePair<char, char> c in keys)
{
    text = text.Replace(c.Key, c.Value);
}
```

[String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx) returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode character in this instance are replaced with another specified Unicode character.

Why do you use `char[] textChar` ? In most cases using `string` is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your code ...

What happens if (for example) you have a key (a,z) and a key (z,b). If you just apply a straight swap all your a's will get turned to z's, and then all your z's to b's. (This means all your a's and z's got turned to b's).

You need to convert items to some intermediate value, then you can then decode as necessary.

```
(a,z)
(z,b)
```

encode

```
(a,[26])
(z,[02])
```

decode

```
([26],z)
([02],b)
```

Comment: there is a complete problem with Gyuzal's whole approach.. this will only work if he is trying to decrypt the same word all the time.. think about his example in the comment he mention taking `mnkore` and having it decrypt to `crypto` stop trying to shortcut..it's not better than someone wanting to `HardCode` because they are too lazy to write a Method or Function to do the proper job..